# Failing VB.NET OleDbConnection. SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, oledbconnection

Realise this has been asked before but i have been unable to find a solution that works in this case.

I am trying to connect to a sql database over a network. The server is 2008 and the application is VB.Net (4).

The offending script is;

```
Dim strConnection As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX;Initial Catalog=MBB;Data Source=NETPC\SQLEXPRESS"
    con = New OleDbConnection(strConnection)
    con.Open()
```

- The user id and password connect and has write permission to the db
  using SQL Management Studio.
- I have tested the connection string using the .udl quick test where
  it worked fine and matched the string above.
- The db is set up to accept both windows & sql server (password
  protected) authentication.

Actual error is;

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information:
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or
>   access denied.

Comment: `connect to a sql database over a network` according to your connection string you are not as I do not see any IP address or anything. Something like this should be there: `Server=IPDADDRESS,PORTNUMBER`

Comment: Is "Data Source=NETPC\SQLEXPRESS" not sufficient to point to an instance on a networked fileserver?

Comment: 1) Is there any reason you're using OleDb instead of SqlClient? 2) have you set the SQL Server to log failed logins so that you can see if the connection attempt got that far? 3) Can you connect to the database with that connection string in, say, SQL Server Management Studio on the client PC? 4) Does it work if you use the IP address of the server, just for testing?

Comment: Try SQL Management Studio from a remote PC - does it still work? Lots of things can go wrong when doing remote connections to SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Thanks for the checklist Andrew;

Comment: 1) The database is being used to hold spatial information linking through to a gis application. Also, i didn't write the program and so would like to avoid changing any fundamentals in the code!

Comment: 2) Yes though being a moron i hadn't checked it. It seems the connection is actually successful but is using NT AUTHORITY\Network Service rather than the login details i'm providing(?) I'll look into that as the Network service may not have permissions..?

Comment: 3) Not sure how to do this. SQL Management Studio connects fine using the login credentials though that is using the normal login UI rather than a string. I have however just connected using VS then taken the connection string from the properties. VS can connect fine but when i use the details in the application the login fails...

Comment: 4) IP+port also fails.